# Calling R functions from C++

Tags: c++, r, call, logistic-regression

I want to perform multinomial logistic regression [using glm()] and do some graphs [gplot()] in C++.

I'm not able to write a function for this kind of regression in C++, but maybe is possible to open R and call glm() function in order to performe it inside of C++, is it? how? I would appreciate any idea.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Calling R Functions from C++](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/r-function-from-c++/)

Comment: Or rather, [RInside](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can via the [RInside](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html) project which provides you with a (very simple) class `R` which instantiates the R interpreter.  You can then pass commands as (possibly multi-line) strings and evaluate via the REPL.

There are numerous examples in the package itself, and on different blog posts.  As it uses [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) extensively, it is also covered in one chapter of the [Rcpp book](http://www.rcpp.org/book/).

Comment: Thank you so much! I've found a lot of information in many websites, I think Rcpp is an awesome tool and it is definitely what I was looking for :)

Comment: The problem I am having right now and that doesn't let me progress with Rcpp is that my g++ compiler doesnt found Rcpp.h header after installing Rcpp with `apt-get install r-cran-rcpp` or with `install.packages("Rcpp")`. And i cannot install R packages under `/usr/include/` directory, any idea? thanks!!!

Comment: Look at the `Makefile` in `examples/standard/` for RInside to understand better.  You need to reflect the R build process and directory layout.  You can of course craft your Makefile by hand, but make sure you use *all* the right components.  Our examples work, so maybe follow them for first steps?